# Onclick menu simultaneously shows its submenu and load its link without hiding the submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is about my JS for menu. I used it in a Joomla template. It shows and hides the submenu and changes the clicked menu class into active, but didn't load the content of the clicked menu.

```
var menu_ul = jQuery('.menu > li > ul > li > ul'),
menu_a  = jQuery('.menu > li > ul > li > a');

menu_ul.hide();

menu_a.click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('active')) { 
        menu_a.removeClass('active');
        menu_ul.filter(':visible').slideUp('normal');
        jQuery(this).addClass('active').next().stop(true,true).slideDown('normal');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
        jQuery(this).next().stop(true,true).slideUp('normal');
    }
});
```

Comment: why did you comment `e.preventDefault();` ?

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle for this

Comment: if you bind click function to anchor tag then you have to use e.preventDefault(); for restricting it to default operation.

Comment: sorry,e.preventDefault is needed.Its wrongly comment.